# Automating the deletion of pipeline

Tags: automation

I have a task to delete 300+ pipelines and deleting them individually is time consuming. Does anyone have some kind of script that could help me accomplish this task? I have tried deleting them individually but that consumes a lot of time to delete all 300+ one by one.

Comment: please add more detail.. which software are you using for starters. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask